Connection of Forward-Backward (FB) asymmetry with particle-antiparticle distribution
I am struggling to understand one thing from the Forward-Backward (FB) asymmetry in hadron collision. For convenience, let's consider a frame where the $Z$ axis is along the difference between the momenta of incoming partons. Now, lets consider a $Z$ boson is produced, which will have longitudinal momenta along the $Z$ axis of our frame (neglecting the small transverse momenta part). It subsequently decays to $e^-e^+$ pair. The $Z$ couples differently to left and right handed particles. How this statement is related to the asymmetry among the positively and negatively charged particles? (arXiv:1509.07645). It is obvious, if we measure left and right handed $e^-$ along some angle, we will get some asymmetry. But we measure Dirac particles, not individually left, and the right part. So, how this FB asymmetry manifest in Dirac particles?
